# Basics asset lines when building a phonegap app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

First, my html locates things relatively on the server. Do I need to change these to the full urls so it knows I don't mean localhost?

Where is the line between what you package in the app and what you grab from the server? Do you package all of your JS and CSS. Do you also grab scripts from the server sometimes? Do you package images and also grab some images dynamically?

Any other things to keep in mind when starting out a port of a web app to phone gap? Just having a hard time figuring out exactly where the lines are usually drawn as far as assets.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you care what happens when your user loses his connection to the internet from his phone?  If not, then you can reference CSS and images from the server.  However, if you use the min version of jquery, you can just embed it all in your application and then you won't have to worry as much about lack of connectivity.

Comment: Ok so it's mostly about offline access as far as what you pack on the client? Does it affect startup speed noticeably to be grabbing assets from the server?

Comment: That's my understanding from classes I've taken on PhoneGap and JQuery.  Any time you grab stuff from the server, the load times can vary.  If you keep the resources packaged, you eliminate that variable from your application.  Personally, I would keep as much local as possible, and try to minimize the size of the resources.